# Removing element from distance matrix

Tags: r, distance, data-analysis

I have a computed distance object with dist(data) and I want to be able to remove data corresponding to the wanted element from the distance object in a way that the data removed distance object is still usable.

```
# Removes outliers for given data until smallest cluster is at the given limit
removeOutlier_1 = function(data, clusters, limitPercent, method) {
  
  outliers = TRUE
  loop = 0
  removedOutliers = 0
  while (outliers){
    # Finding the cluster with minimum elements
    hierData = hclust(distanceData, method = "single")
    hierDataCut = cutree(hierData, k = 3)
    SizeOfOutliers = min(unlist(count(hierDataCut)["freq"]))
    
    # Finding the size of the data
    ddAtt = attributes(distanceData)
    dataSize = ddAtt$Size
    
    # Testing clustering is in wanted percentage
    ratio = SizeOfOutliers / dataSize
    if (ratio >= limitPercent) {
      return(distanceData)
    }
    
    # Removing outliers
    minElementCountLabel = which.min(unlist(count(hierDataCut)["freq"]))
    indexOfOutliers = which(hierDataCut %in% minElementCountLabel)
    
    outliers = outliers + min(unlist(count(hierDataCut)["freq"]))
    loop = loop + 1
    # By usage of found index of outliers remove
    # these points and loop will continue
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you make a small reproducible example? It would be nice to know exactly how you are using the distance matrix so we have a standard for what 'still usable' means.

Comment: Like, if `m <- as.matrix(dist(data))`, and you want to remove the 3rd element, do you consider `m[-3, -3]` usable? I'm not sure... You can still do `as.dist(m[-3, -3])`

Comment: I added code. I identified indexes of the elements that I want to remove from distance data. However, I don't know how can I pinpoint related data of outliers in distance data. Original data consists of 22 columns 2000 rows. However, the distance matrix shows 2000 x 50 which I don't see how distance data is encoded.

Comment: Oh I just saw its 2000 x 2000 not showing in the workspace, I think [-3, -3] will do!

Comment: Now my question is: Is there a possibility that data points can be removed without using as.matrix().

Comment: `methods(class = "dist")` shows only 4 `dist`-class specific methods, `as.matrix`,  `format`,    `labels`, and   `print`. Doesn't look like there are any implemented methods for modifying /subsetting dist matrices. You could write a function wrapping the conversions to and from `matrix` class and doing the subsetting, or `str(dist(matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 5)))` makes the structure look pretty simple - you could write your own. Modify the size attribute and figure out the logic for picking the right elements out of the vector it's built on.